# Split column based on specified position

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose my dataframe is as below, and I want to split `Col1` based on position, in efficient way.

```python
df = sc.parallelize([['sdbsajkdbnasjdh'],['sdahasdbasjda']]).toDF(['Col1'])

+---------------+
|           Col1|
+---------------+
|sdbsajkdbnasjdh|
|  sdahasdbasjda|
+---------------+

pos = [(1,2),(3,5),(7,10)]
```

For example, based on pos list I want result set like below:

```python
d|sa|dbn
d|ha|bas
```

I want efficient way to split data.

My current solution is as below, but it is failing if I provide pos list longer(if there is 10 tuple in list) with EofError.

```python
udf1 = udf(lambda x:  "|".join(str(x) for x in [x[j[0]:j[1]] for j in pos]),StringType())
final_df = df.withColumn("Split",udf1('Col1'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a `udf` for this.

Instead you can use a list comprehension over the tuples in conjunction with [`pyspark.sql.functions.array`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.substring`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring) to get the desired substrings.

Note that the first argument to `substring()` treats the beginning of the string as index 1, so we pass in `start+1`. The second argument is the string length, so I am passing `(stop-start)`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn(
    'Split',
    f.array(
        [
            f.substring(
                str=f.col('Col1'),
                pos=start+1,
                len=(stop-start)
            ) 
            for start, stop in pos
        ]
    )
).show()
#+---------------+------------+
#|           Col1|       Split|
#+---------------+------------+
#|sdbsajkdbnasjdh|[d, sa, dbn]|
#|  sdahasdbasjda|[d, ha, bas]|
#+---------------+------------+
```

To concatenate these together using a `"|"`, wrap the call to `array()` with [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws):

```python
df.withColumn(
    'Split',
    f.concat_ws(
        "|",
        f.array(
            [
                f.substring(f.col('Col1'), start+1, (stop-start)) 
                for start, stop in pos
            ]
        )
    )
).show()
#+---------------+--------+
#|           Col1|   Split|
#+---------------+--------+
#|sdbsajkdbnasjdh|d|sa|dbn|
#|  sdahasdbasjda|d|ha|bas|
#+---------------+--------+
```

Using the DataFrame functions will be faster than using a `udf`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use substr() from pyspark functions to get separate columns for each substring.Then an UDF for rowwise composition to join the columns.Have tried the below code,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

udf1 = F.udf(lambda x : '|'.join(x))

df = df.withColumn('Col2',udf1(F.struct([df.Col1.substr(j[0]+1,j[1]-j[0]) for j in pos])))
+---------------+--------+
|           Col1|    Col2|
+---------------+--------+
|sdbsajkdbnasjdh|d|sa|dbn|
|  sdahasdbasjda|d|ha|bas|
+---------------+--------+
```

As substr() takes startpos and length, we calculate the length. 
Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe going over the string only once will make this more efficient.

(Assuming the current and correct structure of "pos"):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = sc.parallelize([['sdbsajkdbngdfgdfgdfgdfgdgdfgdgdfgdgdgsfhhfghfghdfghdfasjdh'],\
                     ['sdahasdbsdfgsdfhhsfghhkghmaeserewyuouip,mfhdfbdfgbdfgjdtsagasjda']]).toDF(['Col1'])
pos = [(1,2),(3,5),(7,10),(11,15),(20,21),(22,24),(24,26),(26,30),(35,38),(38,42),(42,43),(45,50)]

flat_pos = [x for y in pos for x in y]

def split_function(row):
    return_list = []
    start_copy = False
    flat_pos_index = 0
    temp_list = []
    max_pos = flat_pos[-1]
    i = 0
    while i < len(row):
        if i > max_pos:
            break
        elif i == flat_pos[flat_pos_index]: 
            if flat_pos_index % 2 == 0:
                start_copy = True
            else:
                start_copy = False
                return_list.append("".join(temp_list))
                temp_list = []
            flat_pos_index += 1
        if start_copy:
            temp_list.append(row[i])
        if flat_pos_index + 1 < len(flat_pos) and flat_pos[flat_pos_index] == flat_pos[flat_pos_index + 1]:
                flat_pos_index += 1
                start_copy = False
                return_list.append("".join(temp_list))
                temp_list = []
        else:
            i += 1

    return "|".join(return_list)


udf2 = udf(split_function ,StringType())
final_df = df.withColumn("Split",udf2('Col1'))

final_df.collect()
```

> [Row(Col1=u'sdbsajkdbngdfgdfgdfgdfgdgdfgdgdfgdgdgsfhhfghfghdfghdfasjdh',
>   Split=u'd|sa|dbn|dfgd|d|g|g|fgdg|d|f|g|ghdfg'), 
>   Row(Col1=u'sdahasdbsdfgsdfhhsfghhkghmaeserewyuouip,mfhdfbdfgbdfgjdtsagasjda',
>   Split=u'd|ha|bsd|gsdf|h|k|h|aese|o|p|h|bdfgb')]